# Select value based on two dates in other tables?

Tags: sql, database, select, join, firebird2.5

I have a question according SQL. The database is Firebird but that shouldn't matter much as I would like to use ANSI standard if possible.

I have to select a costrate based on the user qualification and the date the user has been assigned that qualification (I hope this sounds right). I have got tables that look like this:

```
Usertable   Variables      Qualification    Rapportcostrate    Timeaccount
=========   =========      =============    ===============    ===========
UserId      VarId          QuaId            RcrId              TiaID
UserName    VarUserId      QuaName          RcrName            TiaValue
            VarQuaId       QuaRcrId         RcrRate            TiaDate
            VarValidFrom                                       TiaUserId
```

What I need to get now is this:

```
UserName, RcrRate, TiaValue, TiaDate
```

My problem is that the qualification could change at any time and the qualifications that where entered before might still be valid. This should calculate (or select) the

```
RcrRate * TiaValue
```

based on the value in `VarValidFrom` and `TiaDate`. I can't bring them together! :-(

Am I making myself clear? I hope so! Please feel free to ask questions at any time!

== Edit 20 hours later ==

I'm using this sql command at the moment:

```
SELECT RcrRate, VarValidFrom, TiaValue FROM USERTABLE
    JOIN VARIABLES ON UserId = VarUserId
    JOIN QUALIFICATIONS ON VarQuaId = QuaId
    JOIN RAPPORTCOSTRATE ON QuaRcrId = RcrId
    JOIN TIMEACCOUNT ON UserId = TiaUserId
WHERE UserId = XYZ
```

Now let's say table qualifications is filled with several sets

```
 Qualifications          Rapportcostrate
 ===============         ===============
 1    Dummy    1         1   Value01   20
 2    Testing  2         2   Value02   30
 3    Another  3         3   Value03   40
 4    FooBar   4         4   Value04   50
```

If user xyz has three entries in `Variables` like

```
 Variables
 =========
 1    1    1    2008-03-01
 2    1    2    2009-04-01
 3    1    3    2010-05-10
 4    1    4    2013-12-12
```

The expected result should return the `RcrRate` that fits the `VarValidFrom` date to the `TiaDate`. I want to receive only one line per `TiaDate`.

... it's quite a fight to make oneself clear ... ;-)

Comment: Please, post a little try of your code

Comment: Show what you have tried, and be more specific about the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple solutions for this, in the solution below I used CTEs (common table expressions) to split the work in logical units. `cteVarTimes` selects all valid combinations of `Variables` and `Timeaccount`, then `cteMostRecent` selects the latest for the user. In the main select I combine this with the information from `Qualifications` and `Rapportcostrate`.

This solution doesn't work if you need to be able to return rows for all users. In that case you would need to replace `cteMostRecent` with a query that selects rows using a group wise maximum of `VarValidFrom` and `TiaDate` per user.

```
WITH cteVarTimes AS (    
    SELECT v.VarUserId as UserId, v.VarQuaId, tia.TiaValue, tia.TiaDate, v.VarValidFrom
    FROM Variables v
    INNER JOIN Timeaccount tia
        ON tia.TiaUserId = v.VarUserId
    WHERE tia.TiaDate >= v.VarValidFrom
),
cteMostRecent AS (
    SELECT UserId, VarQuaId, TiaValue, VarValidFrom
    FROM cteVarTimes
    WHERE UserId = 1 -- Parameter in real use
    ORDER BY VarValidFrom DESC, TiaDate DESC
    ROWS 1
)
SELECT RcrRate, TiaValue, VarValidFrom
FROM cteMostRecent a
INNER JOIN Qualifications q
    ON q.QuaId = a.VarQuaId
INNER JOIN Rapportcostrate rcr
    ON rcr.RcrId = q.QuaRcrId
```

Comment: Dear Mark, I am not currently in a place where I could test this command but I would like to ask if this would return the correct RcrRate even if there are TiaDates that are before the VarValidFrom date or if this would return only the most recent RcrRate?

Comment: @cico In `cteMostRecent` I order the result by recency (`ORDER BY VarValidFrom DESC, TiaDate DESC`) and only select the first (`ROWS 1`). However, it is entirely possible that my query doesn't do exactly what you need (it selects a single row per user, not per TiaDate)), but I hope it will give you sufficient information.

Comment: Anyway ... merry christmas! ;-)